# Keras: Use the same layer in different models (share weights)

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

**Quick answer:**

This is in fact really easy.
Here's the code (for those who don't want to read all that text):

```
inputs=Input((784,))
encode=Dense(10, input_shape=[784])(inputs)
decode=Dense(784, input_shape=[10])

model=Model(input=inputs, output=decode(encode))

inputs_2=Input((10,))
decode_model=Model(input=inputs_2, output=decode(inputs_2))
```

In this setup, the `decode_model` will use the same decode layer as the `model`.
If you train the `model`, the `decode_model` will be trained, too.

**Actual question:**

I'm trying to create a simple autoencoder for MNIST in Keras:

This is the code so far:

```
model=Sequential()
encode=Dense(10, input_shape=[784])
decode=Dense(784, input_shape=[10])

model.add(encode)
model.add(decode)


model.compile(loss="mse",
             optimizer="adadelta",
             metrics=["accuracy"])

decode_model=Sequential()
decode_model.add(decode)
```

I'm training it to learn the identity function

```
model.fit(X_train,X_train,batch_size=50, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1, 
          validation_data=[X_test, X_test])
```

The reconstruction is quite interesting:

[image]

But I would also like to look at the representations of cluster.
What is the output of passing [1,0...0] to the decoding layer ?
This should be the "cluster-mean" of one class in MNIST.

In order to do that I created a second model `decode_model`, which reuses the decoder layer.
But if I try to use that model, it complains:

> Exception: Error when checking : expected dense_input_5 to have shape (None, 784) but got array with shape (10, 10)

That seemed strange. It's simply a dense layer, the Matrix wouldn't even be able to process 784-dim input.
I decided to look at the model summary:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
dense_14 (Dense)                 (None, 784)           8624        dense_13[0][0]                   
====================================================================================================
Total params: 8624
```

It is connected to dense_13.
It's difficult to keep track of the names of the layers, but that looks like the encoder layer. Sure enough, the model summary of the whole model is:

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
dense_13 (Dense)                 (None, 10)            7850        dense_input_6[0][0]              
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)                 (None, 784)           8624        dense_13[0][0]                   
====================================================================================================
Total params: 16474
____________________
```

Apparently the layers are permanently connected.
Strangely there is no input layer in my `decode_model`.

How can I reuse a layer in Keras ?
I've looked at the functional API, but there too, layers are fused together.

Comment: Did you check out this tutorial? https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

Comment: No, but it looks very interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, nevermind.

I should have read the entire functional API:
https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#shared-layers

Here's one of the predictions (maybe still lacking some training):
[image]

I'm guessing this could be a 3 ?
Well at least it works now.

And for those with similar problems,
here's the updated code:

```
inputs=Input((784,))
encode=Dense(10, input_shape=[784])(inputs)
decode=Dense(784, input_shape=[10])

model=Model(input=inputs, output=decode(encode))


model.compile(loss="mse",
             optimizer="adadelta",
             metrics=["accuracy"])

inputs_2=Input((10,))
decode_model=Model(input=inputs_2, output=decode(inputs_2))
```

I only compiled one of the models.
For training you need to compile a model, for prediction that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Shared layers can directly be accessed from one model to second through list `model1.layers`. What comes tricky is accessing the input layers `tf.keras.Input` (not sure of `tf.keras.layers.InputLayer`, and it's not recommended to use it either) instead as I saw recently these don't assign as simple. But you can access the inputs through `model1.inputs` in the same order the `Input` layers of the model1 were defined. And you can form a new model.

```
in1, in2 = keras.Input(shape=shape1), keras.Input(shape=shape2)
x = Some_Layer(in1)
y1 = Some_Layer(in2)
y2 = Some_model([x, in1, in2])
model1 = Model(inputs=[in1, in2], outputs=[y1, y2])

y3 = Some_model([x, y1])
model2 = Model(inputs=[model1.inputs[0], y1], outputs=[x, y3])
```