# Training two Keras models in tandem with partially shared weights

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm using Keras for a (character) sequence-to-sequence RNN application. Since I have a relatively small set of examples of A -> B, and a much larger set of examples of B, I decided to try an autoencoder approach: first train a network to learn the identity function on B, producing an embedding for members of B, then train a network to learn A -> embedding(B). By combining the second network with the decoder-half of the first network, hopefully it will generalize to produce plausible Bs.

The code, modeled after the [Building Autoencoders in Keras](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) tutorial, looks something like this (several layers, dropouts, regularizations, etc. have been left out for the sake of simplicity):

```
class Example:
    def __init(self, ...):
        # Sets dense_size, rnn, rnn_size, embed_size, input_len, output_len, etc.

    def apply_encoder(self, input_word):
        input_masked = Masking()(input_word)
        input_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(self.dense_size), name='input_dense')(input_masked)
        rnn = self.rnn(self.rnn_size, name='input_rnn')(input_dense)
        embedding = Dense(self.embed_size, name='embedding')(rnn)
        return embedding

    def apply_decoder(self, embedding):
        repeated = RepeatVector(self.output_len, name='repeat')(embedding)
        rnn = self.rnn(self.rnn_size, name='output_rnn')(repeated)
        output_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(self.dense_size), name='output_dense')(rnn)
        output_word = TimeDistributed(
            Dense(self.chars, activation='softmax'),
            name='output_word'
            )(output_dense)
        return output_word

    def build_net(self):
        input_word = Input(shape=(self.input_len, self.chars), name='input_word')
        embedding = self.apply_encoder(input_word)
        output_word = self.apply_decoder(embedding)

        self.autoencoder = Model(input_word, output_word)
        self.encoder = Model(input_word, embedding)

        embed_input = Input(shape=(self.embed_size,), name='input_embedding')
        decoder_output = self.apply_decoder(embed_input)

        self.decoder = Model(embed_input, decoder_output)

    def save_models(self):
        open('models/autoencoder.json', 'w').write(self.autoencoder.to_json())
        open('models/encoder.json', 'w').write(self.encoder.to_json())
        open('models/decoder.json', 'w').write(self.decoder.to_json())
```

First one script trains `autoencoder` on B -> B; then another script instantiates `encoder` twice and trains `encoderA` on A -> `encoderB.predict(B)`; finally, the query script uses `encoderA` and `decoderB` to make predictions.

This all works just fine, but the performance isn't as good as I would like, so what I would really like to do is to train both models in tandem. What I want is two autoencoder models with *separate* encoder halves, but *shared weights* for the decoder halves. Then I alternate between training model A on a batch of A -> B, and training model B on a batch of B -> B, which should update the two encoders on alternate batches, but update the shared decoder on every batch.

My question is, simply, how can I construct these two models so that the weights are shared in the way that I want? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278868/keras-use-the-same-layer-in-different-models-share-weights) is a similar question, but it only explains how to do what I've already done. In case backend matters (it probably doesn't) I can use TF or Theano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make part models using the functional API, and join them as if they were layers.

The difference is that you are creating two decoders (by calling apply decoder twice)

**Encoder A:**

```
aInput = Input(...)
encodedA = LotsOfLayers(...)(aInput)

self.encoderA = Model(aInput,encodedA)
```

**Encoder B:**

```
bInput = Input(...)
encodedB = LotsOfLayers(...)(bInput)

self.encoderB = Model(bInput,encodedB)
```

**Decoder:**

We create just one decoder here:

```
encodedInput = Input(...)
decodedOutput = LotsOfLayers(...)(encodedInput)

self.decoder = Model(encodedInput, decodedOutput)
```

**AutoencoderB:**

Here's the "jump of the cat":

```
autoInput = Input(sameShapeAsEncoderBInput)
encoded = self.encoderB(autoInput)
decoded = self.decoder(encoded)

self.autoencoderB = Model(autoInput,decoded)
```

**Predictor from A:**

Follow the same logic:

```
anotherAInput = Input(sameShapeAsEncoderAInput)
encoded = self.encoderA(anotherAInput)
decoded = self.decoder(encoded)

self.predictorFromA = Model(anotherAInput,decoded)
```

This will make the decoder be the same (sharing weights) for both AutoencoderB and Predictor from A.

Comment: Thanks, I think I see! I'll try to apply it tonight, and then give you the checkmark :)

Comment: It works beautifully. I think what I was missing was that `Input` is like a placeholder, and when you compose two models, the output of the first slots into the Input of the second.